# simple toggle with jQuery

Tags: jquery, toggle

I have two `li`s that I want to toggle on hover, its simple but its not working as I expect:

```
$('ul li:first').hover(function () {
    $(this).hide();
}, function () {
    $(this).show();
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wg9cS/

On hover, I want to hide the first and slideUp the second, but it kind of fluctuates right now.

Comment: *I want to hide the first and slideUp the second...* This basically means you want to hide both.

Comment: Your question is your answer. I want to [toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

Comment: Why the downvotes? Isn't this a valid technical question? Really, SO is getting weird.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because when you hide the element the `mouseleave` event is triggered, so the element is shown and the `mouseenter` event is triggered again, ie an *event loop*.

```
$('ul li:first').mouseenter(function () {
    $(this).hide();
});

$('ul li:eq(1)').mouseleave(function () {
    $(this).prev().show();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wg9cS/2/

Comment: This is it! Possible to animated with slide effect?

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/wg9cS/6/

```
$('ul li:first').hover(function () {
    $(this).slideUp();
});

$('ul li:nth-child(2)').mouseleave(function () {
  $(this).parent().find(":first").slideDown();
});
```

Here's a version that slides. EDIT: undefined's is more elegant.